# When div appears in viewport scroll to top

Tags: jquery, html, css

Finding it hard to find online resources for this technique.

In my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NORSE/YrfBJ/5/) the user can use 'next' or 'prev' to cycle through fullscreen divs. The user can also scroll to get to the next or previous div.

My problem is if the user scrolls then it is hard for them to align the fullscreen div to the viewport so I'd prefer if when the user has most of the div on screen it will automatically scroll to align the top of the div with the viewport.

In my JSFiddle I have included a script which detects if an element is in the viewport, which works but I can't figure out how to add an `if` statement, which when the div comes in to the viewport, align the div to top of screen using `.scrollTo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery inview](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)

Then something like this to run scrollTo:

```
$(elm).bind('inview', function(event, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    scrollTo();
  } else {
  }
});
```

Probably want to run this when the window is resized as well:

```
var timerDelay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();



$(window).resize(function() {
   timerDelay(function(){

   //run inview function

   }, 500);
 });
```

Comment: is it possible when a specific section just inview and than scroll to that section as full screen fit?